# Centered picture in header and footer of LaTeX file

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr, scrlayer-scrpage, footer

I try to add a centered picture in the header and the footer of my documents title page. It should look like in the first picture, that I have just created in a word processing program.

I tried two different ways, to realize this idea in LaTeX:

The first one was based on `scrlayer-scrpage`. I used this package with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage, graphicx}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\includegraphics{Picture1.png}}
\begin{document}
\centering{Title}
\end{document}
```

The result of this code and the package was not like it wanted it to be. This can also be seen in the second picture, that I attached to this post. The picture is just too far on the left side. It is not centered.

Because of that I tried the second way, for which I used `fancyhdr`. For this package, I developed the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics{Picture1.png}}
\begin{document}
\centering{Title}
\end{document}
```

Like you can see in the third picture, this package and the developed code is not the right solution as well, because the picture is not high enough and also to far on the right side.

Because of that I just want to ask if there is any other solution to realize my idea of a centered picture in header and footer of LaTeX file.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

EDIT:

[image: Picture 5]

[image: Picture 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution with `scrlayer-scrpage`. Perhaps there are simpler ones with the `background` or `tikz` packages. The good thing about this is that you can apply this page style whenever you want. You can use it with many classes and `geometry` (margin) layouts. The ruler is just for reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{mwart}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  topmargin,
 % align=t,
  height=5cm,
  %hoffset=7cm,
  %addheight=\headheight,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=5cm]{frog.jpg}}
]{top}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  bottommargin,
  %addheight=\headheight,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\includegraphics[height=\layerheight,width=\layerwidth]{example-image-b}}
]{bottom}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  %outermargin,
  %topmargin,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{measurelayer}

%\defpairofpagestyles[plain.scrheadings]{title}{} %use this if you want plain (bottom number) on 1st page
\defpairofpagestyles{title}{}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{title}{top,bottom,measurelayer}
%\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{title}{top,bottom,measurelayer} %an alternative you want to create an empty style


\title{asdf} \author{asdf} 


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{title}
\newpage 
\setcounter{page}{1}
asdf

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Joseph,

thank you so much for the answer and the code. They really helped me. But now I have one further questions. If I use your code and just delete the "\layercontentsmeasure", a page number appears above the picture in the footer. Is there a way to hide this page number and just start with page number on the second page?

Comment: I also have another problem in connection to my page sizes and the "geometry"-package. I don't know if the problem is dependent to the code, that you have created. Maybe you could also take a short look on my new post to this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561084/ignore-page-sizes-on-title-page

Comment: @SAM_N, See edit.

Comment: @SAM_N, use `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` from the geometry package or the `typearea` package as per the linked answer in your other question.

Comment: I see your edits. They helped me to mask my page number. But the picture in the footer is still not right placed, because the number seems to be still there, but just invisible. I added two pictures to my question, to show you the problem. In the first picture, the page number is still shown. In the second picture I have used your new code, to make the number invisible. Like you can see, is the picture still not right placed.

Comment: @SAM_N, the job of placing the picture is yours, I don't know which picture you want to put there, neither do I know its size or specific location. In `\DeclareNewLayer[` there is place (like `bottommargin`, etc.), `height=`, `width=`, `align`, etc. which you can modify to suit your needs. You can check out other options in the `koma-script` manual.

Comment: {\newgeometry} works like the way I want it to work. But the results of your code on my titlepage changes in the moment, where I start to use the geometry-package. Do you know, why this could happen?

Comment: @SAM_N, you could be more specific about what you did and what you want, otherwise there's no way to know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112559/discussion-between-sam-n-and-joseph).

Comment: After a few tests I found the right alignment for the pictures in the header and in the footer. So the code of @BlackBird answered my question. Thank you!